# The type of member in type is not compatible with of member in type in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application, I have an `ActionResult` in one of my controllers that takes parameters from the client and returns a JSON string.
The problem is, I get the error below when I have null values in one or more of the database records.  I can clear this error by casting all the null values to an empty string in the view table itself, but I'd rather not keep that as a long-term solution.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException: 'Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
>   EFA.msl(16,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=,Unicode=,FixedLength=]' of member 'ScheduledStartTime' in type 'EFAModel.v_DemandList' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.datetime[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=3]' of member 'ScheduledStartTime' in type 'EFAModel.Store.v_DemandList'.'

Any recommendations on how should be approaching this scenario?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetDemandData()
    {
        //get basic parameters from DataTables
        var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
        var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
        var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();

        //Find Order Column
        var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
        var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();

        //find search parameters
        var searchParam = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];

        //build return dataset
        int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
        int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
        int recordsTotal = 0;

        //materialize dataset using serch parameters
        EFAEntities efa = new EFAEntities();

        //*** throws error when database table contains null values ***
        var dataSet = (from a in efa.v_DemandList
                       where a.ScheduledStartTime.Contains(searchParam)
                       select a
                       ).Distinct().OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);

        recordsTotal = dataSet.Count();
        var data = dataSet.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Sample from View Table:

[image: Database Sample]

Comment: This error said, dataType of `ScheduledStartTime` in `EFAEntities` is string (!?) , But in your database this field has `DateTime` dataType. 

are you try compatible their dataTypes ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is clear! Its clearly saying that `ScheduledStartTime` type in `efa.v_DemandList` is not the same type for `ScheduledStartTime` in database table. In your model class `ScheduledStartTime` is `string` type but in your database table its `datatime` type.

So change your `ScheduledStartTime` type from `string` to `DateTime` in your `DemandList` model class.

Then update your query as follows:

```
var dataSet = (from a in efa.v_DemandList
                   where a.ScheduledStartTime.ToString().Contains(searchParam)
                   select a
                   ).Distinct().OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDir);
```

Here I am using `.ToString()` with `ScheduledStartTime` otherwise you cannot use `Contains()` because its a `DateTime` type.

Comment: Thank you.  This turned out to be part 1 of the 2-part problem.  The other part was a mapping issue with the Entity model itself.  I reloaded the data model and it's now running like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

Give default values in your action method.  If it's in fact null, you'll get the default value.  For ints, you need to provide a nullable type.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDemandData(int? start=0, int? length=0, etc)
{
```